# What is the alternative to the "for" loop in the Pyspark code?

Tags: loops, apache-spark, for-loop, pyspark

What is the alternative to the "for" loop in the Pyspark code?
I am new to Pyspark. The task is to run a function for each DataFrame element that:

1. takes the value of this element as an argument `x`,
2. filters the DataFrame on this value `x`,
3. compares (subtract) the received DF with another DF, we get the % matches value - `y`.
4. if `y` < 0.01, saves a pair of values ​​to another object

We have to complete 100 billion of these cycles!
Therefore, it is necessary that they be executed in parallel on all executors.
For this reason, multiprocessing Pool is not suitable as it executes the code on the driver. I tried to use Numba to speed up the loop, but it doesn't work with Pyspark.

I am not applying pyspark map, flatmap and foreach (when I try
access an external object (DF) from the function created in the "map" method - an error occurs:

`_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object`

`cache()` and `broadcast variables` does not improve the situation.

Perhaps there are other methods that will allow to iterate over objects, and get parallel Spark computation on all executors ?

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you...

```py
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col
    
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("genotype_id_res") \
        .getOrCreate()
    
    path_csv = r"C:\Users\HADOOP\gen_rez\genotype_result.csv"
    path_parquet =r"C:\Users\HADOOP\gen_rez\genotype_result.parquet"
    path_result_parq = r"C:\Users\HADOOP\gen_rez\genotype_result_final.parquet"
    
    relativs_list = []
    
    # create df from parquet 
    df_parq = spark.read.parquet(path_parquet).repartition("genotype_id")
    columns_to_drop = ["gc_score", "theta", "r", "log_r_ratio", "x", "y", "x_raw", "y_raw", "ballele_freqs",
                       "genotype_forward", "genotype_result_id"]
    df_parq_all = df_parq.drop(*columns_to_drop)
    
    # create a list to iterate over
    uniq_gen_list = list(df_parq_all.select('genotype_id').toPandas()['genotype_id'])
    
    xx = 24636
    df_genotype = df_parq_all.filter(col("genotype_id") == xx).withColumnRenamed("genotype", "genotype_1")
    
    # create 1st df 
    df_genotype_x = df_genotype.withColumnRenamed("genotype_id", "genotype_id_1").sort("marker_id")
    k = int(df_genotype_x.count())
    
    # compare 1st and 2nd df
    def gen(x):
        df_genotype_y = df_parq_all.filter(col("genotype_id") == x).withColumnRenamed("genotype", "genotype_2")
        df_fin = df_genotype_x.join(df_genotype_y, on=['marker_id'], how='inner')
        df_filt_fin = df_fin.filter(df_fin.genotype_1 != df_fin.genotype_2)
    
        n = df_filt_fin.count()
        c = k - n
        proc_nesovp = c / k * 100
        
        # add results to list
        if 98 > proc_nesovp > 0:
            relativs_list.append([df_filt_fin.select("genotype_id").collect()[0][0], df_filt_fin.select("genotype_id_1").collect()[0][0]])
    
    for x in uniq_gen_list:
        gen(x)
    
    df_final = spark.createDataFrame(relativs_list)
```

Comment: Let me clarify what you are looking for. You need to filter a column and filter by the value 'x'. Then you need to compare it with another dataframe and find percentage matches with that dataframe 'y'. If y<0.01, save the pair(both dataframe) to an object. What do you mean by objects here, is it another file or table?

Comment: I will try to explain the essence of the task. There are 100,000 animals for example. Each of them has 50,000 parameters (markers). We need to compare all the animals with each other. I used the following algorithm: 1) Created a DataFrame with all  animals and markers. 2) Collected the unique animal ID to a separate uniq_gen_list .    To be continued, see the following comment...

Comment: 3) Created the "for" loop in the "for"  loop (here on stackoverflow I posted a simplified code with one loop) - the first loop iterates through the list and for each animal starts a second loop that compares all animals with this animal.  4) if y < 0.01, save only one pair of animal_ID to another object (dataframe or list).    Important !! - the main question is how to avoid "for" loops in this algorithm  in order to get parallel calculations on all executors ?!   (the "for" loop is executed sequentially and not allow to use all available resources)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest some improvements.

- You can avoid repartition. I am not sure if you have any advantage here. It usually involves a lot of shuffle.
- Avoid using toPandas() this usually executed locally on driver/worker nodes.

  Instead to find the unique value you can try. This will return unique genotype_id as a list of Row objects.

Assuming the number of unique genotype_id is small enough to fit in memory.

```
uniq_gen_list = df_parq_all.select('genotype_id').distinct().collect()
```

- You can use 'Semi Join' instead of using 'inner join' to find matches